# Image source path - secure way

Tags: theming, media

which is the secure way of displaying the image_path in src ?

```
`a. <img src = "<?php print check_url($image_path) ?>" />`
b. <img src = "<?php print check_plain($image_path) ?>" />
c. <img src = “<?php print htmlspecialchars($image_path) ?>” />
d. <img src= “<?php print strip_tags($image_path)?>” />
```

Answer (score 0):

check_url basically checks for dangerous protocols in the url and escapes any special characters as HTML entities for output. Normally it's not needed unless outputting a raw external / absolute URL. For relative URLs, Drupal adds the base url automatically.

better to use first(a) option.